# react-native-firebase react-native link issue, how to solve?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-linking

The below error shows up when i try link the library `react-native-firebase`

```
Package react-native-firebase has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Unknown option dependency.platforms.android.buildPatch with value ""\ implementation project(':react-native-firebase')"" was found. This is either a typing error or a user mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.
```

And when i run the app the below error shows

[image]

From my research this happens in react native version 0.60 but have no idea how to solve it ??

Related GitHub issue link below

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2194